# How to Remove the First and Last double quotes in the JSON String in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

Hi guys I wanted to remove the double quotes from the first and last places of the JSON string and I need to place one JSON object in another and I will display my code and my requirement.

```
var sysMsg = new Object();
    sysMsg.timestamp = "100";
    sysMsg.seq  = "5";
    sysMsg.serviceid = "21";
    sysMsg.srcip = "192.168.0.1";
    sysMsg.ver = "1.0";
var sysString= JSON.stringify(sysMsg);
window.alert(sysString);        

var systmMsg = new Object();
systmMsg.sys =  sysString;  
// JSON.stringify(hdrString);
var sysFinal= JSON.parse(systmMsg);
alert(sysFinal);
sysFinal = sysFinal.replace(/\\/g, "");
window.alert(sysFinal);                             

var hdrMsg = new Object();
hdrMsg.appcontext = "context";
hdrMsg.appname  = "appName";
hdrMsg.appid = "identifier";
hdrMsg.cmd = "command";
hdrMsg.timeout = "500";
hdrMsg.option = "optionCommand";
var hdrString= JSON.stringify(hdrMsg);
//window.alert(hdrString);  
var hdrFinal = new Object();
hdrFinal.hdr =  hdrString;                             
var hdrFinalMsg= JSON.stringify(hdrFinal);
hdrFinalMsg = hdrFinalMsg.replace(/\\/g, "");
window.alert(hdrFinalMsg);

var dataMsg = new Object();
dataMsg.CntrlID = "6";
dataMsg.Devinst  = "1";
dataMsg.btnstatus = "btnStatus";
dataMsg.DevID = "33";
dataMsg.value = "true";
dataMsg.status = "errorStatus";
var dataString = JSON.stringify(dataMsg);
//window.alert(dataString);

var dataFinal = new Object();
dataFinal.data =  dataString;                             
var dataFinalMsg= JSON.stringify(dataFinal);
dataFinalMsg = dataFinalMsg.replace(/\\/g, "");
window.alert(dataFinalMsg);

var appData = hdrFinalMsg.concat(dataFinalMsg);
var appFinal = new Object();
appFinal.app =  JSON.stringify(appData);
var appFinalMsg= JSON.stringify(appFinal);
appFinalMsg = appFinalMsg.replace(/\\/g, "");
window.alert(appFinalMsg);

var finalData = appFinalMsg.concat(sysFinal);
var finalMsg= JSON.stringify(finalData);
finalMsg = finalMsg.replace(/\\/g, "");
window.alert(finalMsg);
```

Here I am getting the string as following

```
"{"app":""{"hdr":"{"appcontext":"context","appname":"appName","appid":"identifier","cmd":"command","timeout":"500","option":"optionCommand"}"}{"data":"{"CntrlID":"6","Devinst":"1","btnstatus":"btnStatus","DevID":"33","value":"true","status":"errorStatus"}"}""}{"sys":"{"timestamp":"100","seq":"5","serviceid":"21","srcip":"192.168.0.1","ver":"1.0"}"}"
```

but I want the output as below

```
{"app":{"data":{"Cntrl.ID":"6","Dev.inst":"1","btn.status":"btnStatus","Dev.ID":"33","value":"true","status":"errorStatus"},"hdr":{"appcontext":"context","appname":"appName","appid":"identifier","cmd":"set","timeout":"500","option":"optionCommand"}},"sys":{"srcip":"192.168.0.1","ver":"1.0","serviceid":"21","seq":"5","timestamp":"100"}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I refactored your code so you can have a look how to do this getting rid of all these string operations:

If you work with objects- just work with them and serialize to JSON when you've got what you need:

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/myppwgmb/

And here is how I would have done it:

```
var sys = {
  timestamp: "100",
  seq: "5",
  serviceid: "21",
  srcip: "192.168.0.1",
  ver: "1.0",
};

var hdr = {
  appcontext: "context",
  appname: "appName",
  appid: "identifier",
  cmd: "command",
  timeout: "500",
  option: "optionCommand",
};

var data = {
  CntrlID: "6",
  Devinst: "1",
  btnstatus: "btnStatus",
  DevID: "33",
  value: "true",
  status: "errorStatus",
}

var dataFinal = {
  app: {
    data: data,
    hdr: hdr,
  },
  sys: sys
}

alert(JSON.stringify(dataFinal));
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/myppwgmb/1/

Comment: Thank you very very much sir.. for your help, Incase if I need to get the data in the array dynamically how can I do at that point of situation.Thanks in advance

Comment: so.. what does your array look like? You havn't specified one right now.

Comment: I have to get the data ctrlID DevID and all from another file and I need to update them each time. so I asked you how to update the values dynamically

Comment: @vinod chowdary if you provide a fiddle I'm happy to help

Comment: While fixing this problem we invalidated the question for any other users... Should rename the question.

Answer (score 8):

Here you go

```
var yourString = "{JsonString}";
var result = yourString.substring(1, yourString.length-1);
```

Or you can use `.slice`

```
var result = yourString.slice(1, -1);
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great (I'm using the slice, not sure why you would want to use substring). When you have to use JSON.stringify it adds leading and trailing double quote, this takes care of it very nicely: JSON.Parse(JSON.stringify(STRING_WITH_INVALID_JSON_CHARACTERS).slice(1,-1))

Comment: var thing = "{JsonString: 1}"
undefined
JSON.Parse(JSON.stringify(thing).slice(1,-1))
VM785:1 Uncaught TypeError: JSON.Parse is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:6